# Aggregate over consecutive years

Tags: r

New to r and I'm having difficulty getting the counts I'm after. I have a dataset that contains several columns of various counts per year.  Here is an example:

| huc_code_eight | year | count_1 | count_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6010105 | 1946 | 4 | 4 |
| 6010105 | 1947 | 6 | 0 |
| 6010105 | 1948 | 2 | 0 |
| 6010105 | 1957 | 4 | 4 |
| 6020001 | 1957 | 2 | 0 |
| 8010203 | 1957 | 0 | 0 |

I want to aggregate these counts based upon consecutive years, grouped by `huc_code_eight`.  The expected output would look like:

| huc_code_eight | year | count_1 | count_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6010105 | 1946 - 1948 | 12 | 4 |
| 6010105 | 1957 | 4 | 4 |
| 6020001 | 1957 | 2 | 0 |
| 8010203 | 1957 | 0 | 0 |

I would like to avoid iterating through the data and summing these manually, but, though I've found many examples of aggregating in r, I've been unable to successfully refactor them to fit my use case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a grouping column based on `diff`erence of adjacent elements in 'year' along with 'huc_code_eight' and then `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(huc_code_eight) %>%
   mutate(year_grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(year) != 1))) %>% 
   group_by(year_grp, .add = TRUE) %>% 
   summarise(year = if(n() > 1) 
     str_c(range(year), collapse = ' - ') else as.character(year), 
      across(starts_with('count'), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   dplyr::select(-year_grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  huc_code_eight year        count_1 count_2
           <int> <chr>         <int>   <int>
1        6010105 1946 - 1948      12       4
2        6010105 1957              4       4
3        6020001 1957              2       0
4        8010203 1957              0       0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(huc_code_eight = c(6010105L, 6010105L, 6010105L, 
6010105L, 6020001L, 8010203L), year = c(1946L, 1947L, 1948L, 
1957L, 1957L, 1957L), count_1 = c(4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 0L), count_2 = c(4L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a data.table approach

1. set as data.table,, get the subsequent year, set to 1 if NA, and create run-length id

```
dat <- setDT(dat)[, yr:= year-shift(year),by=huc_code_eight][is.na(yr), yr:=1][,grp:=rleid(huc_code_eight,yr)]
```

2. create the character year (range if necessary, and sum of counts, by id

```
dat[,.(
  year = fifelse(.N>1,paste0(min(year),"-",max(year)),paste0(year, collapse="")),
  count_1=sum(count_1),count_2=sum(count_2)),
  by=.(grp,huc_code_eight)][,grp:=NULL][]
```

Output:

```
   huc_code_eight      year count_1 count_2
1:        6010105 1946-1948      12       4
2:        6010105      1957       4       4
3:        6020001      1957       2       0
4:        8010203      1957       0       0
```